# How to use variable to start new intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a variable:

```
String MyClass = "MyClass"
```

and I want to use it here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

or:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyClass.ToString().class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and it doesn't work... How can I pass the value of `MyClass` to the Intent constructor?

Comment: Before going to start programming ..Just follow the naming conventions..

Comment: I don't think its even possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Java naming convention is that variables should be named starting with a lower case letter, and classes with an upper case one.  This makes your code confusing, because it looks like you're specifying a class, but you aren't.

In fact, the correct answer is to change your String into a Class object using `Class.forName()`:

```
Class<?> newActivityClass = Class.forName(myPackage + "." + myClass);
startActivity(new Intent (this, newActivityClass));
```

There will be exceptions that you will need to catch and handle appropriately.